# Importing Component With Props navigation Without a props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I have problem with my component,

let say my component is something like this

```
const RenderFooter = (props: Props): React.ReactElement => (
  <StickyFooter
    accessibilityLabel="Introduction-Footer"
    primaryButtonText={I18n.t('Introduction-Primary-Button-Text')}
    secondaryButtonText={I18n.t('Introduction-Secondary-Button-Text')}
    onPressPrimaryButton={() => navigate(props, 'LoginPage')}
    onPressSecondaryButton={() => navigate(props, 'RegisterPage')}
  />
 );
```

I want when i try to called this component it doesn't need add argument, but my component need argument when i tried to call it(from this  to  without argument). How to make my component can be like that.

And here is my Props type for this component

```
export type NavigateFunction = (routeName: string, params?: object | undefined) => void;

export type Props = {
  navigation: {
    navigate: NavigateFunction;
  };
}
```

Please help me guys, thanks so much